# Write pyspark DataFrame into phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

Here is my code to write my DataFrame `df` into the phoenix.

```
df.write \
.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.option("table", "TABLETEST") \
.option("zkUrl", "10.10.10.151:2181") \
.save()
```

On running the code, It shows connection status.

```
INFO ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=10.10.10.151:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x4fd269230x0, quorum=10.10.10.151:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 10.10.10.151/10.10.10.151:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 10.10.10.151/10.10.10.151:2181, initiating session
INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 10.10.10.151/10.10.10.151:2181, sessionid = 0x1610f2bcaee003d, negotiated timeout = 90000
```

But it shows following error, and goes on retrying the caller infinitely

```
INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=68188 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=bigdata-datanode,16020,1516377985241, seqNum=0
INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=88386 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=bigdata-datanode,16020,1516377985241, seqNum=0
```

I also added Jars and hbase-site.xml as follows.

```
 /opt/spark/jars
... 
phoenix-core-4.12.0-HBase-1.2.jar
phoenix-spark-4.12.0-HBase-1.2.jar
hbase-common-1.2.0.jar
hbase-client-1.2.0.jar
hbase-protocol-1.2.0.jar
hbase-server-1.2.0.jar
...
/opt/spark/conf
...
hbase-site.xml
...
```